# Example of affine locally symmetric space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Who can give an example of an affine locally symmetric space that is not a Riemanian locally symmetric space?

Comment: When you say affine, I suppose you mean a manifold with affine connection which is symmetric in having involutive automorphisms with arbitrary fixed point with differential $-I$ at that fixed point. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @BenMcKay In locally symmetric, the idea is that locally there are (germs of) such automorphisms. When one requires that for every point there's an (global) involution with this fixed point with differential $-I$, one refers to a *symmetric space*. For an affine structure, the existence of such local involutions is always true, so there would be no point in defining such "locally symmetric affine manifolds".

Comment: @YCor:  I do not understand what you mean by the statement "For an affine structure, the existence of such local involutions is always true."  It is *not at all* true that that for *any* affine connection $\nabla$ on a manifold $M$ there exists a local affine involution of the affine structure in a neighborhood of any $p\in M$ that fixes $p$.  These only exist if the torsion vanishes and the curvature is covariant constant.  See Kobayshi and Nomizu, *Foundations of Differential Geometry*, Volume II, Chapter XI.

Comment: @RobertBryant thanks: I misread Ben's comment and I was thinking of affine manifolds, which is a particular case (flat torsion-free connection).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ben's answer to the question is perfectly fine, but one might also want an example that is not even pseudo-Riemannian, i.e., for which the connection $\nabla$ does not admit any nondegenerate symmetric $2$-form that is $\nabla$-parallel.

The simplest such example is in dimension $2$:  Let $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ with coordinates $x$ and $y$, and let $\nabla$ be the torsion-free connection whose geodesics are either of the form
$$
\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr) = \bigl(x_0 + at,\ y_0 \cos(at) + (b/a) \sin( at)\bigr)
$$
where $a\not=0$ or of the form $\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr) = (x_0,\ y_0 + bt)$.  (Note that, as $a\to 0$, the `generic' formula for the geodesics converges to the special case.)  Note that all of the geodesics leaving $(x_0,y_0)$, other than the special ones with $x(t)$ constant, must also pass through the points $(x_0+k\pi,(-1)^ky_0)$ for $k$ an integer.

The  affine symmetry group (which has 4 components and has dimension $4$) consists of maps of the form
$$
(x,y)\mapsto \bigl({}\pm x+a,\ r\,y+ b_0\cos(x) + b_1\sin(x)\bigr)
$$
with $r\not=0$, $a$, $b_0$, and $b_1$ arbitrary constants.  The geodesic symmetry at $(0,0)$ is $(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$.

The quadratic form $\mathrm{d}x^2$ is $\nabla$-parallel, but there is no $\nabla$-parallel pseudo-Riemannian metric. The holonomy of $\nabla$ acts indecomposably but not irreducibly, as it preserves the line field $\mathrm{d}x = 0$.

There is a 'dual' symmetric space to this one, got by replacing cosine and sine by their hyperbolic counterparts, with similar properties (except for the geodesic focusing).

Comment: Is it clear that this bunch of curves indeed is the set of all geodesics for some torsion-free connection?

Comment: When I learnt the definition of (locally) symmetric space, it was meant to be Riemannian. The current Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space) assumes it to be pseudo-Riemannian. What definition are you using beyond this context?

Comment: @YCor Presumably the definition is as suggested by Ben McKay in a comment to the question

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks for the pointer. This would be an absurd definition (I replied as a comment). I'd rather presume that the OP means pseudo-symmetric spaces.

Comment: @YCor:  The Wikipedia page is misleading, as they only consider pseudo-Riemannian symmetric spaces.  The more general notion of affine locally symmetric spaces is treated in several places, most thoroughly in Kobayashi and Nomizu.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე:  I presume that you want to know what the formula for the covariant derivative is.  If we set $(x,y)=(x^1,x^2)$, then the coefficients of $\nabla$ are $\Gamma^2_{11} = y$ and all others are zero.  One can then easily verify the formula for geodesics.  (For the 'dual' affine symmetric space, one would have $\Gamma^2_{11} = -y$ and all others zero.)

Comment: @RobertBryant Thank you. I now made some graphs which look like everything's fine. Still to be honest I don't understand how such simple Christoffel symbols can produce such complicated behaviour (especially in the first case).

Comment: @RobertBryant, thanks a lot for your example. I am having troubles figuring out how to see the symmetries as a matrix group, do you known an embedding?

Comment: @Chevallier: Yes, though, it's a little tricky.  If you let $$G = \left\{ \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\b&a\end{pmatrix}\ |\ a,b\in\mathbb{C},\  a\not=0\ \right\}$$ and let $H\subset G$ be the subgroup where $a$ is real and $b$ is pure imaginary, this has the right Lie algebra.  However, to get the full group acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$, you need to take the simply connected cover $\tilde G$ and then extend by a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ (so that the group has 2 components) to get the involution that defines the symmetric space. This final group can be embedded into $\mathrm{GL}(6,\mathbb{R})$, but maybe lower works.

Answer (score 10):

[Anti de Sitter space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-de_Sitter_space#As_a_homogeneous.2C_symmetric_space) is not Riemannian, as the stabilizer of a point is not compact

Comment: You might point out that the stabilizer of the usual metric on Minkowski space is not compact, but the affine connection is the same as for the Riemannian metric, so in some sense it is the same affine symmetric space. However, Anti de Sitter space has curvature (of its affine connection) a nonzero multiple of the Lorentz metric, so the stabilizer of a point inside the automorphism group of the affine connection is not compact, and preserves the Lorentz metric and preserves no Riemannian metric.

Answer (score 5):

Having had hard time visualizing the example from the answer by Robert Bryant, I decided to make some graphs for it. They turned out so beautiful that I decided to share them.

Geodesics passing through $(0,1)$:

[image]

Geodesics passing through $(1,-0.3)$:

[image]

And for the "dual" example, geodesics passing through $(0,-0.1)$:

[image]

Geodesics passing through $(1,1)$:

[image]